# Mozilla Firefox не воспринимает Lookbehind Регулярное Выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, firefox, кроссбраузерность

Имеется регклярное выражение:

```
/(?<=")[^"]*(?=")|(?<=')[^']*(?=')/g
```

Которое Chrome воспринимает без каких-либо проблем, в то время как Mozilla Firefox выдёт ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: invalid regexp group
```

Сначала подумал, что Mozilla не умеет в Lookaround и чтобы удостовериться подёргал консольку в DevTool'е Firefox. Однако регулярки типа lookahead:

```
/(?=Something...)/
```

Воспринимает нормально, в то время как на регулярки lookbehind:

```
/(?<=Something...)/
```

Не хочет кушать ни в какую. То ли Mozilla ещё не допилила поддержку Lookaround, то ли это я, кодообезьяна, пишу кривые регулярки.

Comment: Пока что в браузере Mozilla нет поддержки блоков просмотра назад. Да и зачем, можно же использовать группы захвата.

Comment: Да, можно использовать группу захвата, но проблема в том, что требуется исключить символы между которыми происходит захват, то есть из строки " some_name='Some_Value' ", требуется извлечь "Some_Value" без ковычек, на сколько я знаю регулярка типа `/['][^']*(?=')` вытащит и ковычку, a `/[^'][^']*(?=')` и вовсе дёрнет за собой всю левую сторону строки, идущую за ковычкой.

Можно конечно применить replace(/"|'/g,''), но костыли писать не хотелось бы

Comment: Нет, всё возможно и без кавычек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте группы захвата с методом `RegExp#exec(String)` в цикле:

```js
var s = "Строки \"Результат 1\" и 'Результат 2'";
var reg = /"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/g;
var results=[], m;
while (m=reg.exec(s)) {
  results.push(m[1] || m[2]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Можно воспользоваться тем, что мы знаем, что с обеих сторон будут ненужные нам кавычки и упростить код до

```js
var s = "Строки \"Результат 1\" и 'Результат 2'";
var reg = /"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/g;
var results= s.match(reg).map(function(x) { return x.substr(1, x.length-2); });
console.log(results);
```

Comment: А можно ли это выполнить без лишних операций, проще говоря прогнав только `result = (new RegExp(some_regexp...)).exec(some_strnig...)`, просто есть вариант такой костыльной запсии `string.match(/["][^"]*["]|['][^']*[']/g)[0].replace(/\"|\'/g,'')`

Comment: @Max Нельзя без поддержки блоков предварительного просмотра назад.

Comment: Жаль. Придётся пока закинуть Lookaround-регулярку в блок исключений, до тех пор пока Mozilla не допилит Lookaround в SpiderMonkey.